# Skip email 'Unique' validation of Yii model

Tags: php, validation, email, yii

I have written the email rules in one of my Yii model class :

```
array('first_name, last_name, email, password, cpassword, user_type', 'required'),
array('email', 'email','message'=>"The email isn't correct"),
array('email', 'unique','message'=>"Email already exists!"),
```

It is working perfectly for all the scenario like Registration, Login and Update Password but at the functionality of Forgot Password the `unique` validation is also working. I want to skip this validation rule only at the time of forgot password feature in which I'm just want to check the syntax of email and required feature.

So how can we skip this particular `unique` validation for different (Forgot Password) feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use option "except" and add scenario in your action.

```
array('first_name, last_name, email, password, cpassword, user_type', 'required'),
array('email', 'email','message'=>"The email isn't correct"),
array('email', 'unique','message'=>"Email already exists!", 'except' => 'passwordRestoration'),
```

Then, in action

```
...
$model = User::model()->findByPk($pk);
$model->scenario = 'passwordRestoration';
```

Comment: Great Working As i want.

Answer (score 2):

```
array('email', 'unique','message'=>"Email already exists!", 'except' => 'your_forgot_passw_scenario'),
```

Try this one.